# How do I adjust the length of the parameters in IDA?

Tags: ida, functions

In IDA I can easily change the size of the local variables using `Alt+P` and then changing the "Local Variables area" field to the desired value.

However, how can I do this with the parameters size? IDA has misanalyzed the function and got the result that it has about 30 kilobytes arguments when it actually just has 30 kilobytes variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define function type by pressing <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> on its name. Function type includes number and types of parameters.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help, in the stack view of said function, the argument space doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 4):

Open the stack frame window (<kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> or double-click on a variable), then delete bogus arguments with <kbd>U</kbd>.