# Hex-Rays decompiles array to int

Tags: decompilation, dll, hexrays, array

I decompiled one dll using Hex-Ray but it decompiled array type input argument of dll to int. Any idea how to handle this ??

```
double dzSell(int a1, double a2, int a3, int a4, int a5)
```

int a1 is array type in dll

Sadly i can not comment Marware answer so putting it here

so e.g. line like this

```
v9 = *(double *)(a1 + 8 * (v5 - 1));
```

should be changed to ???

```
v9 = *(double *)(a1[2] * (v5 - 1));
```

and int a1 to double *a1 ??

Comment: See [How do I adjust the length of the parameters in IDA?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4047/how-do-i-adjust-the-length-of-the-parameters-in-ida)

Comment: I am personalyl almost giving up on Hex-Rays, it is extremely buggy, right now I am having a simialr problem, except Hex-Rays insist that this double is stored in "rax", except it is a 32bit app, and nowhere in the disasm RAX (or any hack to allow that somehow in 32bit) is ever used, Hex-Rays just assumes extremely wrong.

Comment: @speeder what are you using then ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but if you want to transform a1 to pointer type just pass cursor on the function prototype, press <kbd>Y</kbd> and edit the type of the function argument to, for example, `int *` or whatever pointer type  you need.
That's a type of the function you'll get:

```
double dzSell(
```

**int* a1**,

```
double a2, int a3, int a4, int a5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recall I couldn't handle this case using Hex-rays, I managed to refactor all occurrences of the pattern like:
a1 + 0 is the first index - a1[0],
a1 + 4 is the second - a1[1]
...and so on.

Had some trial and error to distinguish between structs and arrays and it worked.

**UPDATE**
Can't comment.
This statment meaning depends on the context, what's the value of v5?

- v5 - 1 can be an array operation
- But without code, int a1 in the function declaration is the return value (look at the function bottom you'll probably find a return a1;) it's a double array,
  and v9 is the result of *(double *)(a1[2] * (v5 - 1));
- *(double *) : is not actually a double pointer, this cast is added by Hex-rays,(according to the above assumption) it merely means the index of the double array resulted from (a1[2] * (v5 - 1));
- Knowing where v5 come from will be the key, but probably it's just declared and not used

Answer (score 0):

here is the example how Hex-Rays decompile pointers

```
/* The computational routine */
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void myfun2 (double x, double *y, double *z, int n)
{
    int i;
    /* multiply each element y by x */
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        z[i] = x * y[i];
    }
}


/*
int __cdecl myfun2(double a1, int a2, int a3, int a4)
{
  int result; // eax@3
  int i; // [sp+0h] [bp-4h]@1

  for ( i = 0; i < a4; ++i )
  {
    *(double *)(a3 + 8 * i) = a1 * *(double *)(a2 + 8 * i);
    result = i + 1;
  }
  return result;
}
*/
```

so clearly pointer variables are converted to int, it means that casting double * -> int must be done as a2 and a3 are used to access the array. For proper casting i used (uintptr_t)buffer

Comment: According to the StackOverflow rules you need to update the question, not to insert additional answer